# How to change a returned null value in Linq to IQueryable

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I'm trying to populate a listview control with the results of a LINQ query on an IQueryable in C#. This should be the simplest operation in the world, but I'm new to asp.net, c# and visual studio. What I have is this:

```
var query = from i in _db.ItemListView                        
    where (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(key)) ? i.Description.Contains(key) : true &&
        DbGeography.FromText(i.Point).Distance(DbGeography.FromText(geog))*0.0006214 <= rng &&
        (cat != null) ? i.CategoryID == cat : true &&
        (sub != null) ? i.SubCategoryID == sub : true &&
        (min != null) ? i.AskingPrice >= min : true &&
        (max != null) ? i.AskingPrice <= max : true                        
    orderby i.Distance ascending, i.AskingPrice ascending
    select i;
return query;
```

This works, but the `i.Distance` field returned from the database is null by design. I want to populate the `i.Distance` field with the values from:

```
DbGeography.FromText(i.Point).Distance(DbGeography.FromText(geog))
```

`geog` is a variable based on the longitude and latitude of a zip code.

Would someone please show me how to do this?

Comment: Is the problem that your orderby isn't working properly because i.Distance is returning null?  I'm not sure I quite understand your question.  Linq is mostly a read-only paradigm; if you're trying to write data into something, you'll need to do something different.

Comment: i.Distance is always null. I want to change it's value to: DbGeography.FromText(i.Point).Distance(DbGeography.FromText(geog)) and order by the result.

Comment: Iterate through the records in your `query` object, and change the i.Distance field to whatever you need it to be.  Then run a new linq query on the result to get the correct ordering.

Comment: I'm not trying to write the result back to sql server. I'm trying to put a usable distance field into the result set for the listview control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to compute the distance and then select a new object that includes it. Something like:

```
var query = from i in _db.ItemListView 
    let dist = DbGeography.FromText(i.Point).Distance(DbGeography.FromText(geog))
    where (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(key)) ? i.Description.Contains(key) : true &&
        dist*0.0006214 <= rng &&
        (cat != null) ? i.CategoryID == cat : true &&
        (sub != null) ? i.SubCategoryID == sub : true &&
        (min != null) ? i.AskingPrice >= min : true &&
        (max != null) ? i.AskingPrice <= max : true                        
    orderby dist ascending, i.AskingPrice ascending
    select new WhateverYourClassNameIs(constructor parameters here);
return query;
```

Or, you can use

```
select new Whatever { field1=value, field2=value, etc. };
```

Comment: Gah!! I tried three variations of the same thing with no luck, but when I cut and pasted your code, and made a few changes, it worked! Thank you very much Jim Michael!

Answer (score 0):

Sound like you need a custom `select`:

```
...
select new {
   // other fields here,
   ...
   MyNewDistanceField = DbGeography.FromText(i.Point).Distance(DbGeography.FromText(geog)) 
}
```

or alternatively, map your output fields into a custom class:

```
select YourCustomClass {
   // other fields here,
   ...
   MyNewDistanceField = DbGeography.FromText(i.Point).Distance(DbGeography.FromText(geog)) 
}
```

`YourCustomClass` will contain the field definitions you need.